# Publish Angular2 application using Webpack with Build folder

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular. I have setup a small project in which i use npm start it build js and run my application and provides all js in fly. Is there any way in which i can generate a build folder with all complied js and html file so i can host it directly on IIS.

[image: Project Folder Structure]

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = require('./config/webpack.dev.js');
```

config/webpack.common.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const path = require('path');
const rootDir = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');

module.exports = {
entry: {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'app': './src/main.ts'
},

resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
},

module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: 'html-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
            loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
        },
        {
           test: /\.css$/,
           loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader']
        }
    ]},

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html'
        })
    ]
};
```

config/webpack.dev.js

```
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');

const path = require('path');
const rootDir = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {

devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

output: {
    path: path.resolve(rootDir, 'dist'),
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
    filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
    },

    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
    ],

    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        stats: 'minimal'
    }
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>Angular With Webpack</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "angularwebpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "build": "webpack --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --bail"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "^4.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.1.2",
    "@angular/http": "^4.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "^4.1.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.1.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.17.0",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "typescript": "^2.3.2",
    "typings": "^2.1.1",
    "webpack": "^2.5.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

Please let me know if require any additonal information.

Comment: Use Webpack.prod.js  file to get build folder

Comment: please provide ur package.json

Comment: Vignesh i tried to run that but didn't succeed. If you have specific code for webpack.prod.js please provide me

Comment: try ng build (Assuming you have angular-cli installed)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but i am not using Angular-cli as we don't have control over webpack config in that. So used https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular-2-with-webpack-tutorial/  link to create application. Do we have any solution with this